# Insert into Odoo db with a specific id using cursor.commit and psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, psycopg2

I'm trying to migrate some models from OpenERP 7 to Odoo 8 by code. I want to insert objects into new table maintaining the original id number, but it doesn't do it.

I want to insert the new object including its id number.

My code:

```
import openerp
from openerp import api, modules
from openerp.cli import Command

import psycopg2

class ImportCategory(Command):
    """Import categories from source DB"""

    def process_item(self, model, data):

        if not data:
            return
        # Model structure
        model.create({
            'id': data['id'],
            'parent_id': None,
            'type': data['type'],
            'name': data['name']
        })

    def run(self, cmdargs):
        # Connection to the source database
        src_db = psycopg2.connect(
            host="127.0.0.1", port="5432",
            database="db_name", user="db_user", password="db_password")

        src_cr = src_db.cursor()
        try:
            # Query to retrieve source model data
            src_cr.execute("""
                SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, c.name, c.type 
                    FROM product_category c
                    ORDER BY c.id;
            """)
        except psycopg2.Error as e:
            print e.pgerror

        openerp.tools.config.parse_config(cmdargs)
        dbname = openerp.tools.config['db_name']
        r = modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(dbname)
        cr = r.cursor()

        with api.Environment.manage():
            env = api.Environment(cr, 1, {})
            # Define target model 
            product_category = env['product.category']

            id_ptr = None
            c_data = {}
            while True:
                r = src_cr.fetchone()
                if not r:
                    self.process_item(product_category, c_data)
                    break

                if id_ptr != r[0]:
                    self.process_item(product_category, c_data)
                    id_ptr = r[0]
                    c_data = {
                        'id': r[0],
                        'parent_id': r[1],
                        'name': r[2],
                        'type': r[3]
                    }

        cr.commit()
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could find was to use reference attributes in others objects to relate them in the new database. I mean create relations over location code, client code, order number... and when they are created in the target database, look for them and use the new ID.

```
def run(self, cmdargs):
    # Connection to the source database
    src_db = psycopg2.connect(
        host="localhost", port="5433",
        database="bitnami_openerp", user="bn_openerp", password="bffbcc4a")

    src_cr = src_db.cursor()
    try:
        # Query to retrieve source model data
        src_cr.execute("""
            SELECT fy.id, fy.company_id, fy.create_date, fy.name,
                    p.id, p.code, p.company_id, p.create_date, p.date_start, p.date_stop, p.special, p.state,
                    c.id, c.name
                FROM res_company c, account_fiscalyear fy, account_period p
                WHERE p.fiscalyear_id = fy.id AND c.id = fy.company_id AND p.company_id = fy.company_id
                ORDER BY fy.id;
        """)

    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print e.pgerror

    openerp.tools.config.parse_config(cmdargs)
    dbname = openerp.tools.config['db_name']
    r = modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(dbname)
    cr = r.cursor()

    with api.Environment.manage():
        env = api.Environment(cr, 1, {})
        # Define target model 
        account_fiscalyear = env['account.fiscalyear']
        id_fy_ptr = None
        fy_data = {}

        res_company = env['res.company']

        r = src_cr.fetchone()
        if not r:
            self.process_fiscalyear(account_fiscalyear, fy_data)
            break

        company = res_company.search([('name','like',r[13])])
        print "Company id: {} | Company name: {}".format(company.id,company.name)
```

The previous code is only an extract from the whole source code.

Comment: It would be nice to actually see the insert.